# Bash script for parsing and processing specific lines of a text file

Tags: bash, text

I have the following text file

```
40 timesteps took 58.320842 seconds
greetings 0
80 timesteps took 58.048400 seconds
greetings 0
120 timesteps took 59.459687 seconds
greetings 0
```

What I would like to do is parse only the lines containing the seconds, add them together and print out the final result.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know much of bash...! All I know is that I have to use some regular expressions with sed. But I have no idea how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is well suited for this type of processing.

To deal with floating point precision, you can use `printf` with a *format-string* for each variable involved.

There is also another way which sets the format-string for *all* ***evaluated*** variables. The formatting is applied during evaluations (which internally use `sprintf`. The controlling built-in variable is `OFMT`.  See [Built-in Variables That Control awk](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gawk/gawk_116.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"   # $1 is the 1st command line parameter
awk -vOFMT="%.6f" '/ took /{ secs+=$4 } END{ print secs }' "$file"
```

---

Using `sed` is more involved, because it cannot do any calculations and even `bash` itself cannot do floating point arithmetic, so you need to use something like `awk` or `bc` in any case.

If you really want to use sed:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"   # $1 is the 1st command line parameter
{ sed -nr 's/.* took ([0-9.]+).*/\1+/p' "$file" |tr -d '\n'; echo 0; } |bc
```

Comment: I used kraftan's solution but liked your explanation better!Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple shell command:

```
grep timesteps <file-name> | awk '{x += $4} END{printf("%.5f", x)}'
```

Change the number in the `printf` statement to your preferred output precision.

Comment: Excellent! Could you also tell me how can I give the <file-name> as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

The awk solutions are good answers. For fun, here is a Ruby answer...

```
ruby -e 'puts readlines.inject(0) { |m, v| m += v.split[3].to_f }' < file
```

...or perhaps...

```
ruby -e 'puts readlines.map { |x| x.split[3].to_f }.reduce(&:+)' < file
```

...to pass the file as a parameter to a script...

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts $<.map { |x| x.split[3].to_f }.reduce(&:+)
```